# Сохранение данных при вводе в TextField которая находиться в ячейке таблицы

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

У меня есть таблица с 50 ячейками и в каждой есть TextField.

Как при редактировании ячейке сразу обновить данные в массиве для отображения таблицы? Чтобы при прокрутке данные они не пропали?

Comment: А как Вы сохраняете данные в массив сейчас?

Comment: Да. Из него и формируются данные для таблицы.

Comment: храните данные не в UI, а в модели (массиве). в cellForRow заполняйте UITextField значением из модели.

Comment: Я их и храню  в массиве! Вот как изменить массив сразу после внесения изменений в текстовое поле?